# skipping incompatible libGL.so

Tags: linux, mesa

I have freshly installed Fedora 19 x86_64 on my PC.
I wrote a simple OpenGL program, but failed to compile it.

```
    gcc -o quad quad.c -lX11 -lGL -lGLU
    /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.1/../..        /../libGL.so when searching for -lGL
    /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libGL.so when searching for -lGL
    /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libGL.so when searching for -lGL
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have MesaGL and other libraries in place (i.e. /usr/lib) then what's wrong ?

Comment: Have you installed any additional GL libs, perhaps through an ATI or NVIDIA graphics driver install?

Comment: Yes I installed ATI Catalyst Drivers v 13.6 beta.

Comment: The dark side of both the NVIDIA and ATI installers is that they REPLACE the GL libs.

Comment: You are also running ccache, which I would recommend against until you have resolved the issue. It /shouldnt/ matter but I would suggest limiting the points at which the process could break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed.

I removed ATI Catalyst Driver v13.6 beta by executing "**aticonfig --uninstall**"
REBOOT
compile the program with same commands, and it was success :)

Now I **reinstalled** ATI Catalyst Drivers v13.6 beta
REBOOT and compile the program again,
It builds SUCCESSFULLY !!

Don't know what was wrong, but I have OpenGL working now :)

Comment: Thank you. Uninstall & reinstall the ATI driver did work for me.

Answer (score 6):

For me, something was wrong with the library symlinks:

```
$ locate libGL.so | egrep ^/usr | xargs file
/usr/lib/libGL.so:                     symbolic link to `/usr/lib/libGL.so.1'
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1:                   symbolic link to `/usr/lib/libGL.so.1.2'
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1.2:                 symbolic link to `/usr/lib/fglrx/fglrx-libGL.so.1.2'
/usr/lib/fglrx/fglrx-libGL.so.1.2:     ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
/usr/lib64/FGL.renamed.libGL.so.1.2.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=46121ec8b16424a8b65a0cf11c3f9730ae0e49f5, stripped
/usr/lib64/libGL.so:                   broken symbolic link to `libGL.so.1.2.0'
/usr/lib64/libGL.so.1:                 symbolic link to `/usr/lib64/libGL.so.1.2'
/usr/lib64/libGL.so.1.2:               symbolic link to `/usr/lib64/fglrx/fglrx-libGL.so.1.2'
/usr/lib64/fglrx/fglrx-libGL.so.1.2:   ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

So /usr/lib/libGL.so pointed at a 32-bit lib and /usr/lib/libGL.so was a broken link. I fixed the /usr/lib64 version to point correctly at libGL.so.1 (and the /usr/lib version to point at the 64 bit version for good measure) and this seems to have gotten my code compiling.

Comment: I have the same problem, Could you please tell me how exactly you fixed the /usr/lib64 version to point correctly at libGL.so.1?

Comment: Remove the bad link, then recreate it pointing to the correct file with `ln -s`

Comment: I'm in the same occasion with you and I solved this problem in your way. But do you have any idea about why is this happening? I didn't do anything after I installed MesaGL. And it just happened when I try to compile.

Answer (score 1):

There are warnings about incompatible versions of libGL, and also about incompatible GCC libraries. I think you might have a 32 bit version of gcc installed on a 64-bit OS. Try

```
file -L `which gcc`
```

to check on this.

Comment: That's the output of the "which" command, but not the whole pipeline I've shown, which should say something more like "64-bit ELF executable"

Comment: my bad, /usr/lib64/ccache/gcc: symbolic link to `../../bin/ccache'

Comment: /usr/lib64/ccache/gcc: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0xcc138400640fee53799c8e85ffa20df35843d246, stripped

Comment: I'd run the file -L command on the GL lib it is attempting to link against, very curious to see what the output is.

Answer (score -2):

Install freeglut-devel : 
**# sudo yum install freeglut-devel**